# Clicking on button using Selenuim Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click the button on a webpage but using `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//img[@src()='birt/images/ExportReport.gif']").click()` does not work, any idea what am I missing out on? Thank you.

```
input type="image" name="exportReport" src="birt/images/ExportReport.gif" title="Export report" alt="Export report" class="birtviewer_clickable"
```

Comment: Can you share the URL you are scrapping?

Comment: Hi there, the url is: https://maximomobile.*.com/maximo/bridge/webcontent/birt/images/ExportReport.gif, where * is my company's name

Comment: And what is your comapny's name?

Comment: I'm not too comfortable with sharing it, is that important?

Comment: That's the only way I can test my answer right

Comment: But this button is behind a login, without it, the button cannot be accessed. Maybe I can test your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You are using this xpath

```
//img[@src()='birt/images/ExportReport.gif']
```

that will look for img node.

However, in the `HTML` that you've shared, I see you have an `input tag` instead. So, changing `img` to `input` should get the job done iff it's locating the right node in the HTML-DOM.

**Code1:**

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@src()='birt/images/ExportReport.gif']").click()
```

**Code2:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@src()='birt/images/ExportReport.gif']"))).click()
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Hello, unfortunately, these 2 codes did not work. The src is not unique, the second one is located here https://imgur.com/0ZdKSxl

Comment: Bit confusing, so you are saying that we have two nodes in html? If so, Can you share both of them here ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I'm quite new at this, I hope this image is clearer: https://imgur.com/sPTOkWu
As you can see, the first src is the green highlighted one near the top and the second is at the bottom in the HTML I sent earlier.

Comment: okay I see two web elements, which one you want to select? if you want to select first one, then the xpath that I have given should work, however for second `(//input[@src()='birt/images/ExportReport.gif'])[2]` use this xpath.

Comment: Apologies, it is the second one I'm trying to select. I have tried 

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//input[@src()='birt/images/ExportReport.gif'])[2]").click()` and 

`WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//input[@src()='birt/images/ExportReport.gif'])[2]"))).click()`
But it still doesn't work, did I do something wrong? This is a picture of the button I am trying to click, if it helps https://imgur.com/a/c5jMzbP

Comment: Please read this section above `Steps to check:` and see if we have unique entry in HTML-DOM or not. If we have a unique entry and if the above xpath locates the right element, then run this command `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//input[@src()='birt/images/ExportReport.gif'])[2]").click()` and let me know what's the exception that you've got.